# How to prove that $rankA + rankA^{T} \geq rank(A + A^{T}) $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I can see that this inequality means that adding together columns with rows of a matrix can't increase number of linearly independent rows or columns, but I don't really see why. If $A$ has $n$ linearly independent rows (and columns) then $A^{T}$ also has $n$ linearly independent rows (and columns). What exactly happens when we're adding them together?

Comment: It's always true that $\text{rank }A+\text{rank }B\ge\text{rank}(A+B)$. Consider the images of $A$, $B$ and $A+B$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\text{range }(A + B) \subseteq \text{range }(A) + \text{range }(B),$$
because every vector in the range of $A + B$ can be written as the sum of a vector in the range of $A$ plus a vector in the range of $B$ like so:
$$(A + B)v = Av + Bv.$$
Both $\text{range }(A + B)$ and $\text{range }(A) + \text{range }(B)$ are linear subspaces, so it follows that
$$\dim \text{range }(A + B) \leq \dim (\text{range }(A) + \text{range }(B)) \leq \dim \text{range }A + \dim \text{range }B.$$